# Browsers return error "the operation is insecure" when using Paho MQTT

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I made a small web chat with JavaScript and Paho MQTT, but neither Firefox nor Edge (i.e. the browsers I have tried) let me connect to the broker `broker.hivemq.com`. Firefox says that the operation is insecure.

[image: image of error]

I use this MQTT client:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's my [GitHub project](https://github.com/obsiddev/metrochat).

Comment: Is your page loaded via HTTPS? and how are you connecting to `broker.hivemq.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load a page via HTTPS it will NOT allow you to make a none secure WebSocket connection to the remote host. You MUST use wss:// (secure websockets)

Comment: I worry that people reading this will takeaway from it that one should switch to http and fix the wrong problem...

Comment: It is a perfectly valid solution if that meets the threat model for your application

Comment: I 100% agree with you. People that are going to turn off TLS to make this work are mostly not at that level of sophistication to understand the difference, and the ones that are don't need the warning.